# How to sort Alphanumber String in Java

Tags: java, collections

```
{"SAMPLE:1-1-8-SAM#1", "SAMPLE:1-1-8-SAM#13","DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#13",DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#26,DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#8}
```

So, the output will be
Alphabetical order and numeric also

```
DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#26
DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#13
DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#8
SAMPLE:1-1-8-SAM#1
SAMPLE:1-1-8-SAM#13
```

I have tried in ArrayList. The thing is, it is taking entire string as a string. But I want to sort string as well as number.Here what I got the output

```
DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#8
DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#13
DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#26
SAMPLE:1-1-8-SAM#1
SAMPLE:1-1-8-SAM#13
```

Comment: if the output on the top is desired output, how do you sort ascending and then having #26 in front of #13?? What exactly is the logic of the sort that you need?

Comment: ho, sorry, i didn't see that. but anyway, I think you got my point

Comment: Do you wish to sort all numbers or just the final number after the `#`?

Comment: all numbers and String!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to sort the strings and consider all numbers you can use a combination of regex and Java 8.

Consider a string like the following:

```
"SAMPLE:1-2-8-SAM#1"
```

This can be split up using a regular expression to a `String[]` like this

```
String s = "SAMPLE:1-2-8-SAM#1";
String[] arr = s.split("((?<=[:\\-#])|(?=[:\\-#]))");
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

The output would be:

> [SAMPLE, :, 1, -, 2, -, 8, -, SAM, #, 1]

This means that we can treat index 0 like a `String` and index 2, 4, 6 and 10 as `Integer`s.

So, in order to use that for sorting the following code can be used:

```
String[] strings = {
        "SAMPLE:1-2-8-SAM#1",
        "SAMPLE:1-1-8-SAM#1",
        "SAMPLE:1-1-8-SAM#13",
        "DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#13",
        "DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#26",
        "DEMO:1-1-4-SAM#8"
};

final List<String> sorted = Arrays.stream(strings)
        .map(str -> str.split("((?<=[:\\-#])|(?=[:\\-#]))"))
        .sorted(Comparator
                .<String[], String>comparing((arr) -> arr[0])      // String compare
                .thenComparing(arr -> Integer.valueOf(arr[2]))     // Integer compare
                .thenComparing(arr -> Integer.valueOf(arr[4]))     // Integer compare
                .thenComparing(arr -> Integer.valueOf(arr[6]))     // Integer compare
                .thenComparing(arr -> Integer.valueOf(arr[10])))   // Integer compare
        .map(l -> Arrays.stream(l).collect(Collectors.joining()))  // Map it back to a String
        .collect(Collectors.toList());                             // Collect it to a List for further processing
```

It is not super-readable but it works as per the OP:s question. If you also use some static imports the code is a bit easier to read.

---

However, my recommendation is to create a `Comparator` that does the sorting which will be more readable (and thereby easier to maintain in the long run).

Answer (score 4):

You will have to write your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that splits up the strings into lexical parts and numerical parts and then compare them with the appropriate operator.

The following is a pseudo-code implementation of `Comparator`'s only method `compareTo` to illustrate what I'm suggesting:

```java
public void compare(String s1, String s2) {
  String[] e1 = split(s1);
  String[] e2 = split(s2);

  int n = Math.min(e1.length, e2.length);

  int ret = 0;

  for (int i = 0; ret == 0 && i < n; i++) {
    if (isNumber(e1[i])) {
      ret = compareNumerical(e1[i], e2[i]));
    } else {
      ret = compareLexical(e1[i], e2[i]));
    }
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: @Thomas, why not `Comparator` along with `paralletSort` from Java 8 API ? like, `parallelSort(T[] a,Comparator<?super T> c)`... it is much efficient because it assigns sorting tasks to multiple threads available in the thread pool.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori - This might be a good choice under the right circumstances but the overhead of Thread handling must be taken into account. For short arrays it's probably not worth it (?).